# Find derivative of $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ in distribution

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, distribution-theory

Find derivative in distribution of $f(x)=\lfloor{x}\rfloor=E(x)$

$$E(x)≤x≤E(x+1)$$

- Answer is :

$$\lfloor{x}\rfloor '=\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\delta_{k}$$

I don't have any idea about how to.

Can you assist?

I'm too thankful

Comment: The floor function clearly has a zero derivative at non-integers. But since it increases in value by one at each integer intuitively we need a Dirac at each integer.

Comment: Why not take a test function and apply the definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$. For any test function $\phi(x)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle f',\phi\rangle&=-\langle f,\phi'\rangle\\\\
&=-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lfloor x\rfloor \phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_{n}^{n+1} n\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n (\phi(n+1)-\phi(n))\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n \phi(n+1)+\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n\phi(n)\\\\
&-\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (n-1) \phi(n)+\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty n\phi(n)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \phi(n)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \langle \delta_n ,\phi\rangle\\\\
&= \langle \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\delta_n ,\phi\rangle
\end{align}$$

Hence, in distribution $$\lfloor x\rfloor' = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-n)$$as was to be shown!

Comment: @Matk Viola very nice done . I like it thanks!

Comment: @Brian Moehring  yes sir just a simple typo , thanks!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you!  Much appreciated.  And nice catch of the typographical error.  I've edited accordingly.